# Access $scope variable inside directive template and update controller $scope.variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have create a simple directive with an input element and span. Using the directive I created two custom elements with isolate scope. Now, I am trying to get the sum of the data entered in the input element of the directive. But really can't figure out how to do that.
Here is the my controller and directive :

```
angular.module('mapp',[])

.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.total = 0;  
}])

.directive('customElement',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            data: '=info'
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data1">\
                    <span>{{data1}}</span>'
    }
});
```

I'm looking to sum up `data1` of all directives elements and update `$scope.total`. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="mapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">

        <custom-element info="a"></custom-element>
        <custom-element info="b"></custom-element>
        <br/>
        <br/> Total: <span>{{total}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npodupn8/1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwkqo41/) is a working fiddle

```
angular.module('mapp', [])

    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;
    $scope.a = 0;
    $scope.b = 0;
    $scope.$watchCollection('[a,b]', function () {
        console.log('watch');
        $scope.total = $scope.a + $scope.b;
    });
}])

    .directive('customElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=info'
        },
        template: '<input type="number" ng-model="data">\
                    <span>{{data}}</span>'
    }
});
```

[A version without $watch](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwkqo41/1/)

[A version with ng-repeat](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwkqo41/2/)

Comment: Great !! it does the job. One more doubt. What if the directive is being looped and dynamically created, is there still a way to achieve the above functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically created?  ng-repeat?

Comment: Added a version that demonstrates ng-repeat

Answer (score 3):

`Total: <span>{{a+b}}</span>` this would also work in the html without using a `$watch` or function from the controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can do with $watch

**Controller**

```
.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.test = {};
    $scope.test.a = 0;
    $scope.test.b = 0;
    $scope.$watch('test',function(newVal,oldVal){
        $scope.total = $scope.test.a + $scope.test.b
    },true)
    $scope.total = 0;
}])
```

Directive change `ng-model="data1"` to `ng-model="data"`

```
template: '<input type="number" ng-model="data">\
                    <span>{{data}}</span>'
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/npodupn8/4/)